# Finding Jordan Canonical form but equation for finding the generalized eigenvector becomes inconsistent

Tags: linear-algebra, jordan-normal-form

I have been given a problem to find the Jordan Canonical form of the following $ 3 \times 3 $ matrix

$$ A=
\begin{bmatrix} 
3 & 0 & 1 \\
-4 & 1 & -2 \\
-4 & 0 & -1 
\end{bmatrix}
$$

I have been told to do this using the transformation matrix way, wherein $A$ can be written as

$$
A = TJT^{-1}
$$
where $T$ is the modal matrix analogue which contains the eigenvectors and/or the generalized eigenvectors as columns and $J$ is Jordan Canonical form of A. Doing some matrix operations on the above equation, $J$ can be obtained as

$$
J = T^{-1}AT
$$

Coming back to the problem, I have found the characteristic equation and got all three eigenvalues as $1$. I found eigenvectors by

$$
Ax_1 = \lambda x_1
$$

Solving this I got two linearly independent eigenvectors, since I was getting only 1 pivot after row transformation operations on $A$ the above equation must give me two solutions. I got these

$$
x_1 = \begin{bmatrix}
0 \\ 1 \\ 0
\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}
1 \\ 0 \\ -2
\end{bmatrix}
$$

For the next step, according to my textbook, I should get a generalized eigenvector by solving for $x_2$

$$
Ax_2 = \lambda x_2 + x_1
$$

The textbook example only shows one possible value for $x_1$, so clearly I've got a problem regarding which one of the two eigenvectors I got, should be chosen for the next step.

But even without considering that, I have yet another problem

$$
Ax_2 = \lambda x_2 + x_1 \\
(A - \lambda I)x_2 = x_1
$$

If I find out the matrix $A - \lambda I = A - I$, I get

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 0 & 1\\
-4 & 0 & -2\\
-4 & 0 & -2
\end{bmatrix}
$$

which forms an inconsistent set of equations to solve, because of the repeated row but different values in the rows of (either) $x_1$. So I can't proceed further to get $x_2$.

Have I done something wrong, or is there some pre-condition to be checked on $A$ that I missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to choose an eigenvector that is also in the column space of the matrix $A-\lambda I$. In this case, by looking at the matrix you have and at your eigenvector basis, one sees that an eigenvector that will work is $\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\-2\end{bmatrix}-2\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\0\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}1\\-2\\-2\end{bmatrix}$.

Hence, you have two eigenvectors $ v_1=\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\-2\end{bmatrix}$ and $v_2 = \begin{bmatrix}1\\-2\\-2\end{bmatrix}$. Define $v_3 = \begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}$ and note that $(A-I)v_3 =v_2$. Now using $T=[v_1,v_2,v_3]$ we will get the Jordan form.

Note that if we just wanted the Jordan form $J$, without caring about what T is, then it is sufficient to know that A has $2$ eigenvectors. For then, as A is a $3\times3$ matrix the only possibility for the matrix $T$ is that it contains $2$ eigenvectors and one generalized eigenvector, which is mapped to one of the eigenvectors under $A-I$. Hence, we will get two Jordan blocks, one of size $1\times 1$ and one of size $2\times 2$. So up to ordering of the blocks $J=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: I need some clarification, is this one of the possible values of $x_2$ ? If so, that can't be right because then the transformation matrix T would become singular (because linearly dependent columns), and inverse of T would not be defined.

Comment: okay, I think I got it, this should be the value of $x_1$, right?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Then you solve for the generalized eigenvector.

Comment: if i use any other linear combination of those two vectors, should that also work? because seeing that if I add the two eigenvectors i get $x = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ -2 \end{bmatrix}$ which won't satisfy the generalized eigenvector equation ($(A-I)x_2 = x$)

Comment: The linear combination cannot be chosen arbitrarily as the resulting vector needs to lie in the column space of $A-I$. To pick a vector in a systematic manner you could calculate the intersection of the column space and the eigenspace. In low dimensions, you can usually solve it by inspection as I did above.

Comment: Cracked, I like the other method that is occasionally taught, finding the non-genuine eigenvectors first, give them integer elements when $A$ has all integers, use simple matrix multiplication to force necessary relations. I think I have just the one book that teaches both methods.

Comment: Indeed, that method is perhaps more natural. However, I think it is a good idea to try to solve these kinds of relatively simple exercises by inspection first though. It can save you some tedious computations.

Comment: @CrackedBauxite, i tried solving it further this morning but i'm still getting stuck at the first generalized eigenvector, i used $[1 -2 -2]^T$ as $x_1$ and I got the equation $2a+c=1$ out of $(A−\lambda I)x_2=x_1$, where $x_2 = [a b c]^T$, similar to $x_1$ should I also look for an $x_2$ that is in the column space? if so i would again get a scaler multiple of $x_1$ only, i would not get any of the vectors that Will Jagy got.

Comment: It doesn't matter which vector you choose for the generalized eigenvector. You don't need any more vectors after this one so you will be done. The reason we needed an eigenvector in the column space was so that we could find a generalized eigenvector mapping to it.

Comment: don't I need one exact eigenvector (from $Ax_1 = \lambda x_1$) and two generalized eigenvectors (from $Ax_2 = \lambda x_2 + x_1$ and $Ax_3 = \lambda x_3 + x_2$) for $T$?

Comment: I have added some more details to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I like the backwards method: choose the generalized eigenvector(s) with integer elements and see what is forced. Since   $A-I$ gives two genuine eigenvectors, we hold off on that... The minimal polynomial gives the size of the largest Jordan block (always!).  That is, $(A- I)^2 = 0, $  so we look for any nice looking vector for which $(A-I)^2 w = 0$ but $(A-I) w \neq 0.$  I like $w=(0,0,1)^T$
Next we are forced to use $v= (A-I)w = (1,-2,-2)^T.$ A genuine eigenvector that is independent of $v$ could be $u = (0,1,0)^T$

The resulting matrix, your $T,$ is those three as columns in order $u,v,w$

This method allows us to force $T$ to have all integers, with the likelihood of some rational entries in $T^{-1}$ because $\det T$ is most likely not $\pm 1$

Alright, they set this one up with determinant $-1.$

$$
T=
\left(
\begin{array}{rrr}
0&1&0 \\
1&-2&0 \\
0&-2&1 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

$$
T^{-1}=
\left(
\begin{array}{rrr}
2&1&0 \\
1&0&0 \\
2&0&1 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$